# Getting region name in SageMaker endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

In SageMaker endpoint, hosting my custom container with Python code, I need to access the region name. I tried the AWS_REGION and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION variables but they are not defined. Do you maybe know some way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the region for Boto3/CLI calls to be made in the container you can do this by setting the environment variables yourself in the container yourself.

Why do you need the region name? If you want to identify the region the endpoint is deployed in, the ARN of the endpoint will contain the region.

`arn:aws:sagemaker:<region>:<accountID>:endpoint/<endpointName>`